# Core Data - crashes when modifying database on device

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data, read-write

I have an app using Core Data that works fine on the simulator but crashes on a device. I've looked at the posts about copying a read/write copy of the sqlite file from main bundle into the library but it still crashes. It crashes when I save a new object, or modify an existing one, but only on some, but not all of the entities (?!). It is fine on the simulator. The error I get after an object save and popover onto the delegate view controller is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The left hand side for an ALL
>   or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.'

I have added the following code into AppDelegate, but with no discernable effect:

```
NSString *dbPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BCP" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dbPath];
  NSString *libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *targetPath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"BCP.sqlite"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:targetPath]) {
        // database doesn't exist in your library path... copy it from the bundle

        NSError *error = nil;

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:dbPath toPath:targetPath error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have a predicate somewhere that uses "ALL" or "ANY" on a relationship that isn't "to-many". Show us the code that crashes. Add an exception breakpoint.

Comment: Try deleting the app from the device, cleaning the project and running it again.

Comment: Fogmeister was right - I had changed from to many to to one and hadn't changed the methods accordingly. Interesting that the simulator tolerated it but the device didn't.